# What is better generate random IDs at runtime or keep them handy before?

Tags: string, algorithm, random, unique

I am writing an app and need to do something functionally similar to what url shortening websites do. I will be generating 6 character (case insensitive alphanumeric) random strings which would identify their longer versions of the link. This leads to 2176782336 possibilities ((10+26)^6). While assigning these strings, there are two approaches I can think about.

Approach 1: the system generates a random string at the runtime and checks for it uniqueness in the system, if it is not unique it tries again. and finally reaches a unique string somehow. But it might create issues if the user is "unlucky" maybe.

Approach 2: I generate a pool of some possible values and assign them as soon as they are needed, this however would make sure the user is always allocated a unique string almost instantly, while this could at the same time also mean, I would have to do plenty of computation in crons beforehand and will increase over the period of time.

While I already have the code to generate such values, a help on approach might be insightful as I am looking forward to a highly accelerated app experience. I could not find any comparative study on this.

Cheers!

Comment: Even if 1000000 unique IDs are used, there's still only a 1/2177 chance of getting a duplicate on the next generate. 1/2177^N if you generate N numbers. Basically, a really low probability so it will be fast enough, you can't be that unlucky.

Comment: @Dukeling: i still believe answer by zim-zam is the same i was thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in similar situations is to keep `N` values queued up so that I can instantly assign them, and then when the queue's size falls below a certain threshold (say, `.2 * N`) I have a background task add another `N` items to the queue.  It probably makes sense to start this background task as soon as your program starts (as opposed to generating the first `N` values offline and then loading them at startup), operating on the assumption that there will be some delay between startup and requests for values from the queue.

Comment: i was thinking the same, but let's say when the total possibilities start to exhaust, then this task would start becoming lengthier.

Comment: @whizzzkid How many ids are you assigning?  With your setup you can assign up to a billion ids and have less than a 50% chance of a collision, which means that on average to add `N` ids to the queue you'll only need to generate and test `2*N` ids.  Increase that to assigning 1.5 billion ids, and you'll still only need to generate and test `3*N` ids in order to add `N` ids to the queue.

Comment: @whizzzkid If you're expecting to use up **all** of the ids (and then presumably switching to 7 character ids) then you may want to generate all 36^6 ids and then shuffle them - store `N` ids per file and load the ids from another file when your queue falls below, say, `.2 * N`, then delete a file when you've used all if its ids (you'll need to account for the case when your program crashes after it's only used half of the ids from a file). If you're willing to forego some randomness, then you can instead generate and shuffle all ids starting with 1, then all ids starting with 2, etc